# How do I make JavaScript PhoneGap apps to remember something?

Tags: javascript, cordova, store, mobile-application

I want to make a JavaScript PhoneGap app being able to store information, like log in data or for a savegame, but obviously I'm not able to write into files with JavaScript ansd since this is supposed to work offline I am also not able to run a server script that manages it for me.
I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this and I'd be very thankful for your help!

Comment: What about LocalStorage or WebDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).  Local storage only stores strings, so you'll probably want to serialize JSON when saving to local storage. See  is a [breakdown of local storage size by browser](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/).

```
var myData = { foo: "bar" };
localStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(myData));

var retrievedDataString = localStorage.getItem("myData");
var retrievedData = JSON.parse(myDataString);
```

Comment: I was going to suggest to use a database system due to the type of requirement (gamer's profile info), but I guess stringifying the json objects and saving them would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Just like "dfsq" sayed, have you tried localStorage?

```
localStorage.userToken = "SomeData";
```

But remember, localStorage can only storage a max of 5mb of data and all the data is stored as String, for more than this or more flexibility with the type you will need another solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a database. One of the good options are Firebase. https://www.firebase.com/ . Try its tutorial. It gives you offline capability as well. Also its FREE. ( For 50 concurrent connections )

Answer (score 0):

What about using SQlite plugin for phonegap/cordova?

[Cordova SQLite plugin](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

Answer (score 0):

Many users, many solutions. In my mind the best way to do this would be with a WebSQL Database. You may have a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/de/features/storage - i know this site is in german but the graphic displayed there will give you a little overview. You'll see where you can use what kinds of databases.

WebSQL works like a charme and every of my apps with databases uses webSQL Databases. Its not just a good solution, it is the best one to be consistency. Normally you're using a MySQL DB on a WebServer for Logindata etc. if you have already all your data localy stored inside a WebSQL Database, you have also consistency of your